# PayPal subscription, add outstanding balance to next bill for subscription button

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I have a plain html button for subscription payments (sample code attached).
Now when a subscription payment fails, paypal tries again in 5 days and then cancels the subscription (I think after this second try).
I want it to let payments fail for a few months before canceling it.
I seen this is called "add outstanding balance to next bill".
But I don't know how to implement this in my current code.

- add missed payments (outstanding balance) to next bill after a few missed payments.
- specify after how many missed payments to cancel (e.g 3 months).
- automatically collect outstanding balance

```html
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="EXAMPLE-SELLER-ID">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Service at example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thank-you">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://example.com/try-again">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're looking for the parameter name `sra`, which can be set to `1`.

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#recurring-payment-variables